# Is it possible to use NOT in a regular expression in TextMate?

Tags: regex, textmate

I have a Matlab project which I'm working on in the OSX editor TextMate. I need to find all instances of a certain word, let's say it's "foo", that is not either preceded by a "." or succeeded by a "/".

However, I cannot find any way to search for regular expressions that are negatively defined like this. Does anyone know if it is possible to search for something like "A preceded by anything other than B"?

(TextMate uses the [Oniguruma regular expression library](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions) by K. Kosako.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You want to use this bit of the syntax:

```
(?=subexp)         look-ahead
(?!subexp)         negative look-ahead
(?<=subexp)        look-behind
(?<!subexp)        negative look-behind
```

In your case, `(?<!\.)foo(?!/)`

Comment: Awesome! I overlooked those in the documentation. Thanks :)

Comment: This is a brilliant solution that also takes into account the occurrence of the word `foo` at the beginning or end of the text.

Comment: Great information! Look behind solved a big issue for me! [Checkout this](https://regex101.com/r/FiVZGX/1/)

Answer (score 15):

The ^ (circumflex or caret) inside square brackets negates the expression. So to find a "foo" not preceded by a "." would be:

```
[^.]foo
```

Comment: that should be `(^|[^.])(foo)` and also it also matched one extra character.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! This is the variant I tried initially, but I messed up the syntax and tried ^[\.] instead of [^\.] :P

Comment: This won't work. You want all characters except '.' which means 'any character'. You need to escape it: (^|[^\.])(foo)

Comment: [stuf] matches the letters s,t,u,f.  Contents of square brackets are NOT an expression, they are a list. [^.] is anything but period.  [^\.] is anything that isn't a back slash or a dot. ^ and - are the only characters that sometimes have a special meaning in []

Comment: Why not `[^\.]foo`?